# How can I stick the footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

How can i set the footer for different pages on the following site:

http://www.optimimo.com/

http://www.optimimo.com/home/contact

I am little confused on how to fix the footer at the bottom of different pages.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ryan+fait+sticky+footer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) will help you

Comment: It's a confusing question

Comment: Sir how can i fix the footer for different page the position will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your question! However, this has been closed as "Too Localized" because you have not included the relevant code here, in your question. This means once your issue is fixed, or the link breaks, this question won't be useful to help anyone in the future who shares your issue. If you can edit in the relevant code/information, this may be able to be reopened.

Comment: You should search for *sticky footer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `height:100%` to `html, body` and `#pagewidth`

Now add `position:absolute; bottom:0` to footer

```
#pagewidth {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
}
#footer {
font-family: 'PT Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
width: 100%;
background-color: #2d2d2d;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 24px 0;
margin: 20px 0 0;
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
line-height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Ah i was just about to answer the same thing. It is correct though.

Comment: This is the wrong solution

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#footer {
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'PT Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 24px 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did (@Sowmya, you forgot to take care of some edge-cases)

```
html { height: 100%; }
body {
    min-height: 100%; /* Otherwise your page will have no background if the content is longer than one screen-height */
    position: relative; /* To let the footer allways be on page-bottom, not at one-screen-height */
}

#pagewidth { padding-bottom: 5em /* aprox. the height of the footer ... */ }

footer#footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; width: 100% /* Fixes some IE mis-alignments ... */ }
```

If you want the footer always to be at the bottom of the screen, set the footer to position fixed.